# Force Regenerate Thumbnails Not Working

Tags: post-thumbnails, thumbnails

Alright so I'm writing a new theme for my blog and i've decided to change the size of large media from 640 to 820. I have used the force regenerate plugin and updated the media settings so that large is 820 wide but when I look at all my posts it's not working.

Here are the screenshots:

[image: Media Settings]

[image: Inserting/Updating Media]

I know I could go through every post and update the caption code to say 820 wide but I need to know why is it not saying 820 wide when I try and update or insert media because it's really annoying me because I don't plan on spending ages updating every post

Comment: image sizes change do no magically update your content. Wordpress have no way to know which size should be changed and which doesn't.

Comment: Yea if I re-insert images they still say Large 640. I know I could go into the code after and change the width but that seems like a bit of a hack

Comment: ok, misunderstood earlier. Have you tried to disable all plugins and switch to the default theme to see if the problem is with any of them?

Comment: I did that and it still inserted the images at the wrong size but at the correct size for the theme